# font-family-list function still returning nil

Tags: fonts

I have a hard time with fonts. I downloaded the package `intlfonts-1.2.1` from the FSF website, and after some `configure`, `make` and `install` I get the following directory where all fonts are installed : `/usr/local/share/emacs/fonts/bdf`.
So I added to my init.el the following line:

```
(add-to-list 'bdf-directory-list "/usr/local/share/emacs/fonts/bdf")
```

I evaluated in a scratch buffer the function `font-family-list` but it returns `nil`.
What should I do then? I played around a bit with `set-frame-font` but as long as `font-family-list` is empty I suppose this is nonsense.
Thanks for your advice, the documentation I read so far did not help that much.

I'm using emacs 24.5 under Mac OSX.

Comment: If you start with `emacs -q` and evaluate `font-family-list`, is the result `nil`?  On OSX 10.11.6 with Emacs 25.1.1 from https://emacsformacosx.com/ , I get `("Abadi MT Condensed Extra Bold" "Abadi MT Condensed Light" "Al Bayan" "Al Nile" "Al Tarikh" "American Typewriter" "Andale Mono" "Arial" "Arial Black" "Arial Hebrew" "Arial Hebrew Scholar" "Arial Narrow" ...)`

Comment: @lawlist, yes I get still nil with emacs-q. I run a non GUI Emacs.

Comment: The issue may be with font limitations in the terminal version of Emacs.  Someone more familiar with fonts for Emacs in the terminal on OSX will need to help you further.

Comment: I see, thanks...I might switch to a GUI version at some point.